# Write to binary file in Julia

Tags: julia

I need to record some data to binary file in Julia. On C I use next code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
FILE* out = fopen( "test2.bin", "wb" );
if( out==NULL )
    return 1;

putc(49,out);
fclose(out);
}
```

and got expected result(I look as char in hex-editor):

```
1
```

After rewrite the code to Julia,I got the follow code:

```
out =  open("test.bin","w")
write(out,49)
close(out)
```

but result is:

```
1.......
```

From documentation I know that function `write` returns the number of bytes(in my case it 8 but should be 1).

So my questions: 
1. What I am doing wrong?
2. How right write to binary file in Julia?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You on right way. The reason is that 8 it is size of Int, so you need used explicit type conversion Int to Char if want write as Char:

```
write(out,Char(49))
```